# Assert failed in OnInitDialog()

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc, assertion

So I have an "assertion failed" error message when I want to run my program. I understand that it means that somewhere a condition that should be true isn't but I don't know how to correct that.

The error concerns the following line :

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CEdit::SetReadOnly(BOOL bReadOnly)
   { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hind)); return (BOOL)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, EM_SETREADONLY, bReadOnly, 0L); }
```

So I get that it's about the "Read Only" condition, but I don't know where to correct that.

I am new in C++, so sorry if I forgot to put important information in my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IsWindow assertion fails when window is not created yet (or destroyed). Your code is in a wrong place. For example, if you try to do this in a dialog constructor, move the code to OnOnitDialog. BTW, the question title looks a bit strange...

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was the title of an old question I wanted to ask and never did, and it was automatically recovered, and I didn't pay attention. I am going to try what you advised thanks !

Comment: It's on the OnInidialog actually ... Sorry, since I don't really understand everything I'm doing, I really don't know what info I should add..

Comment: I assume `m_hind` is a typographical error. Although confusing since you should not type the code a second time just copy and paste from the IDE.

Comment: Should I have these lines on my OnIni Dialog :
`BOOL SetReadOnly(
   BOOL bReadOnly = TRUE 
);`

Comment: That is a prototype so no.

Comment: It is not clear what your issue is. You can use SetReadOnly on a child window of your dialog in OnInitDialog() provided the child was created. Are you dynamically adding controls to your dialog?

Comment: Haha, I know but I'm actually working on the code on another computer (which is not connected to the internet)

Comment: I don't know how to answer (I'm sorry I'm such a noob). All I can say is that in my OnIniDialog, I have several "Edit Control" variables set on SetReadOnly as follows : `C_RecCount1.SetReadOnly();` in my .cpp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help! Finally, after going through the whole code line by line, I realized in DoDataExchange I mixed up and put twice the same variable at some point instead of two different ones ... So I don't really know how that got me that error but I thought I'd keep you updated in case someone makes the same absent-minded mistake and gets that error :)

Answer (score 2):

The OnInitDialog function contains a call to the base class function

```
CDialog::OnInitDialog();
```

Move your calls to SetReadOnly to after that line.  The edit control variables are only initialized after that line.